# Can Chiaki play any instruments besides violin and piano?

Tags: nodame-cantabile

Chiaki is a talented violinist and pianist, and also an aspiring conductor. In the classical music industry, it's fairly common for people who are that talented at multiple instruments to know at least a few more. Is Chiaki known to play any other instruments besides violin and piano?

[image]

Comment: I don't remember seeing him playing something different ...

Comment: @looper If you've seen/read a sizable portion of it, feel free to write that as an answer. In the worst case that you missed it, someone else can always write the correct answer later.

Answer (score 4):

As @Looper mentioned, Chiaki only plays the violin and the piano. The lack of additional instruments can be attributed to his dedication in becoming a world-class conductor.

Comment: Additionally, when he was playing that duet with Mine (episode 2 I think), he says that he's been playing the violin and piano since he was 3, but that he was way better at the violin. So he entered the piano department at the school so that he could get better at the piano. Never a mention about any other instrument.